# How can I install Ubuntu One for Windows onto a memory card or USB flash drive?

Tags: installation, windows-7, ubuntu-one-windows

Is there a way to install the Ubuntu One app for Windows onto a memory card or flash-drive?

Edit: I want to do this because it would be handy to have U1 on my school laptop in order to keep all my documents synced etc. Sadly, I don't have administrative rights, so I can't install it onto the hard drive itself. Copying it over does not work since it requires that vcredist_x86.exe is installed, but as I said; I don't have admin privileges.

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide some rationale for wanting to do this? I'm a little worried that you're setting yourself up for some painful experiences.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu One must be installed into the OS in order to access the cloud. If you have Windows installed on a USB, then YES.

The personal cloud that brings your digital life together. For Windows XP, Vista and 7.

also available for iPhone and Android

[Source](https://one.ubuntu.com/downloads/windows/)

Answer (score 0):

The installer doesn't do it, but everything you need to run it is in `c:\program files(x86)\ubuntuone` so it should not be terribly hard to do. If you succeed or need any help, please let me know!

Comment: Simply copying over the files doesn't work, just gives a load of errors.

Comment: It needs the vcredist_x86.exe installed in order to run, but the machine I'm trying to use it on isn't administrated by me and doesn't have this installed. :(